# how to format data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the  following values from database:

99, 12, 12.2222, 54.98, 56, 17.556

Now I want to show that values like below:
 99%, 12%, 12.22% , 54.98% , 56%, 17.55%

Please give me any suggestion to acchive this.

Comment: What is the type of the returned values ??

Comment: u can concate string direct to the query also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very easy in C#:

**[EDIT]**

```
var val = 99.569;
string result = string.Format("{0:0.##}%", val);
```

You can take a look for `Format` method of string class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

and I recomend you to take a look on custom format strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: @Archibald: Yes, you are right. but in this case we should use `##` instead of `00`.

Comment: @Anton: OP also ask about the value 99 which should be 99% but if he implement your way in that case 99 will be 99.00%

Comment: @rerun: I've already done it. Downvotes is engine of improvements! :)

Comment: @Vijjendra: No. if format equals to `0.00` the result would be 99.00% but if format equals to `0.##` trailing zeroes would be omitted

Answer (score 2):

Use the ToString method that takes a string format - the format you want is "P2" or the custom format #0.##%. Both of these formatting options multiply by 100, expecting your data to be in standard percent format so you will need to divide to accomadate and use it.
 To use ToString without the divide you can use "#0.##\%" which will format the numeric part and include the percent sign as a literl, this is the equivilent for ToString as the format from Anton Semenov's answer using the string.Format function on this thread.

[Msdn article - Standard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
[Msdn article - Custom Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator)

Comment: I had forgotten, but was working on the revision above. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

to formart 12.2222 use `f`

```
 string.Format("{0:f}%", 12.2222); //output 12,22%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Out

```
        List<double> myList = new List<double>();
        myList.Add(0.1234);
        myList.Add(99);
        myList.Add(12.1234);
        myList.Add(54.98);
        foreach (double d in myList)
        {
            string First = string.Format("{0:0.00%}", d); //Multiply value by 100
            Console.WriteLine(First);                    
            string Second = string.Format("{0:P}", d);//Multiply value by 100
            Console.WriteLine(Second);  
            string Third = string.Format("{0:P}%", d.ToString());//Use this One 
            Console.WriteLine(Third);  
            string Four = d.ToString() + "%"; //Not a good idea but works
            Console.WriteLine(Four);
            Console.WriteLine("=====================");  
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I have made a little trick here {0:P} will multiply your given value by 100 and then show it but you just want to place a % sign after value so first convert the given value to TOString than apply {0:p}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the number of decimal places to 2 (ie. not 12.2222%, but 12.22%), then use:

```
val.ToString("0.00") + "%"
```

Note that this will round the number off, so 12.226 would be shown as 12.23%, etc.